# Class doesn't seem to work. Wont return image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm pretty new to classes in objective-c. I'm testing out one I made unhiding an image from the class on the click of a button, everything compiles and runs but it's not working out for me, nothing shows up when I click. Am I doing this all wrong? Tried to include everything I think is relevant in the code below, obviously the images for the other parts of the class are there but I didn't include them below seeing as I'm just testing one image from it.

question.m file -

```
#import "Question.h"
@implementation Question
@synthesize image;

@end
```

question.h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#ifndef Question_h
#define Question_h
#endif /* Question_h */


@interface Question : NSObject
{
    UIImageView *image;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *image;

@end

@class Question;
@interface Controller : NSObject
{
    Question *firstQuestion;
    Question *secondQuestion;
    Question *thirdQuestion;

}
@property(nonatomic, retain) Question *firstQuestion;
@property(nonatomic, retain) Question *secondQuestion;
@property(nonatomic, retain) Question *thirdQuestion;

-(void) Question;
```

ViewController.m -

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Question.h"

@synthesize question1, q2, q3, firstaid;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

 firstTierQuestions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
}

- (IBAction)Question:(id)sender {
Question *firstQuestion = [[Question alloc] init];
firstQuestion.image = question1;
firstQuestion.a1 = _answer1;
firstQuestion.a2 = _answer2;

[firstTierQuestions addObject:firstQuestion];

- (IBAction)generator:(id)sender {

        for (Question *firstQuestion in firstTierQuestions) {
        [firstQuestion.image setHidden:NO];
    }
}
```

viewController.h -

```
#import "question.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *question1;  
    NSMutableArray *firstTierQuestions; 
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *generator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *question1;

- (IBAction)generator:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *Question;

@end
```

Comment: Remove `@synthesize image;` and `UIImageView *image;`. For the rest just watch a few tutorials on YT to learn the basics. You can't expect people to spend their time explaining the basics.

Comment: It would help if you could post a minimal *compilable* example of your code. I want to be able to just copy/paste your code into a project to work with it but I can't.

Comment: Where/when do you provide an image for the image view?